# Windows 10 activation failed with error: 0x803F7001

Tags: windows-10, ssd, fresh-install

I tried to activate Windows 10.  It failed with error 0x803F7001 and a description stating that the "Previous version was not activated".  Following are the steps I performed to get to where I am now:

1. I have a laptop which had a single HDD and an OEM copy of Windows 8.1 pre-installed on it.  I had no other drives.
2. In July 2015, I took advantage of the free Windows 10 upgrade and successfully upgraded from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10.  I did *not* perform a clean install, just a regular upgrade from 8.1 to 10 on my HDD.  I had no activation issues – everything worked like a charm.
3. Yesterday I physically removed my HDD from my laptop and inserted my SSD.
4. I performed a clean install on the SSD using the Windows 10 media creation tool.

Windows 10 will not activate. I am getting Error: 0x803F7001 with a description stating that the "previous version of Windows on this machine was not activated" which is false as described in my steps above.

I understood that the Windows activation servers blueprint your machine, taking the key from the BIOS and using that as a method of activating Windows 10.  I also understood that in order for this to happen, you have to *first* upgrade to Windows 10 normally from Windows 7 / 8 (not clean install) after which you can perform a clean install.  I have done just that.  Then I swapped out my HDD (with the activated Windows 10 on it) for an SSD to perform a clean install.  What did I do wrong?  How can I resolve this?

Comment: What version of Windows 8.1 and what version of Windows 10 do you have and what build is it?

Comment: "I also understood that in order for this to happen, you have to first upgrade to windows 10 normally from windows 7 / 8 (not clean install) after which you can perform a clean install." - This is no longer true since, Windows 10 Version 1511 (Threshold 2) was released.  Even if it was true, it does not apply to your machine, since it has had Windows 10 installed in the past.

Comment: I don't have windows 8.1 - refer to point # 2 in my post.  As for windows 10, I had it installed for a good 6 months on my HDD, and it went thru updates during that period so it should be on the latest version.

Your response does not offer any solutions.

Comment: I fully understand you don't have Windows 8.1.  You had Windows 8.1 installed on the machine in the past though.  I am asking what version of Windows 8.1 came installed on the machine.  *I cannot answer your question without the answers to my questions.*  If you don't want to provide specific information, that is fine, I won't be submitting an answer without it though.  You can't activate `Windows 10 Professional` if the machine came with `Windows 8.1 Core` or `Windows 8.1 Single Language`.

Comment: [ShowKeyPlus](https://github.com/Superfly-Inc/ShowKeyPlus) will let you view your Windows 8.1 key allowing you to activate your Windows 10 installation either by manually changing the produce key or through phone activation.  In research, this error was reportedly solved, by simply rebooting the machine.

Comment: As far as I remember I had windows 8.1 single language edition.  

I went ahead and retrieved my activation key from my 8.1 (had it written down somewhere) typed it in and it worked.  I was surprised as I remember reading that typing in the activation key from a previous version of windows simply would not work.  Maybe it does work once one has upgraded to windows 10 at least once on a specific machine or windows has changed its way of doing things.

Either way, you pointed me to the solution: How do I accept your answer?

Comment: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-10/activation-errors-windows-10

Comment: "I was surprised as I remember reading that typing in the activation key from a previous version of windows simply would not work." - See my second comment, I already addressed your miss understanding, I always have my reasons for questions I ask.  You can't accept a comment as an answer, and I won't be posting an answer, since this ended up being an simple activation error with Windows 10 and there are plenty of questions with answers that cover the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to activate windows 10](http://superuser.com/questions/1000959/unable-to-activate-windows-10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Microsoft:

> #### Error code: 0x803f7001, 0x800704cF
>
> This error means we didn’t find a valid Windows license for your PC.
>   *[Basically, your hardware didn't match what's in Microsoft's database.]*
>
> You’ll need to use a valid product key to activate Windows. Your product key should be in the confirmation email you received after buying Windows, in the box Windows came in, included with the packaging your PC came in, or on the Certificate of Authenticity (COA) attached to the back or bottom of your PC.
>
> If you’re activating Windows 10 (Version 1511 or higher), you can use a valid Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows 8.1, or Windows 10 product key.
>
> If you have a valid product key, use it to activate Windows:
>
> 1. Select the Start button, then select **Settings > Update & security > Activation**.
> 2. Select **Change product key**, and then enter the 25-character product key.

*From https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/10738/windows-activation-errors*

Seeing that you had a valid copy of Windows 8.1, presumably you still have the licence sticker containing the product key?  You can simply use that to activate Windows 10.

I recently reinstalled Windows 10 (with no hardware change) and yet was faced with the same error.  Luckily I was able to dig up my Windows 7 product key and that activated Windows 10 for me successfully, using the steps above.